# PHP simple sql search for login

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

i had some problems with this code, seen some guides and arrived to this. I just started php few days ago. How exactly do you do a search of database, then compare the user input to the database username and password?
the $sqlQuery i left it empty for the sql search and maybe someone can explain what you call the "->" symbol in the loop?

I allready managed to understand and do a sign up but the tutorials never explain exactly what is going and just type.
Thanks.

```
<?php
    include 'db.php';
    include 'info.php';

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $sqlQuery = '';
        $result = mysqli_query($connection,$sqlQuery);

        if($result->num_rows > 0){
            session_start();
            echo 'welcome';
        }else{
            echo 'failed';
        }

    }


?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Log In</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="login.php">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username">
        Username: <input type="password" name="password">

        <input type = "submit" value = " Submit "/><br />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can search through the database using the SQL WHERE Clause: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Answer (score 1):

**PHP PDO login with session** - It's secure

**index.php,general message.php, logout.php, site life.php** (this page for session and put it in the other pages by required)

**Database:**
[image]

**connection.php**

```
<?php 
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mg";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$options = array(
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
);

try{
$conn = new PDO($dsn,$username,$password,$options);
} catch (PDOException $e){
echo "Error!".$e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

**index.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
header("location: general message.php");
}
require "connection.php";

if(isset($_POST['login'])){
$user = $_POST['username'];
$pass = md5($_POST['password']);
$messeg = "";

if(empty($user) || empty($pass)) {
    $messeg = "Username/Password con't be empty";
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username=? AND 
  password=? ";
    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array($user,$pass));

    if($query->rowCount() >= 1) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
        $_SESSION['time_start_login'] = time();
        header("location: general message.php");
    } else {
        $messeg = "Username/Password is wrong";
    }
}
}

?>
```

**Site life.php** (and I will put it in the the other pages by require "site life.php")

```
//The lives of session is one hour 60*60=3600 

<?php

    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    if((time() - $_SESSION['time_start_login']) > 3600){
        header("location: logout.php");
    } else {
        $_SESSION['time_start_login'] = time();
    }
    } else {
    header("location: logout.php");
    }
     ?>
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("location: index.php");
?>
```

**General message.php** I put this in the header (to make a refresh every hour):

```
// 60*60=3600 one hour

<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="3600" >

<?php 
require ('site life.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `->` is an object operator. so you can access attribute `num_rows` from `$result`.

This is the naive example (vulnerable to SQL injection) to give you an idea, it works.

```
<?php
    include 'db.php';
    include 'info.php';

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection,$sqlQuery);

        if($result->num_rows > 0){
            session_start();
            echo 'welcome';
        }else{
            echo 'failed';
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Log In</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="login.php">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username">
        Username: <input type="password" name="password">

        <input type = "submit" value = " Submit "/><br />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should really use a prepared statement or at least escape the POST variables to avoid sql injection.

Comment: yes and I said its naive. but it works for the provided question.